# How to display a grid of images that have different aspect ratios?

Tags: images, page-layout, grids

If I have a grid of images, let's say political cartoons, that have differing aspect ratios and cannot be cropped, how can I display them in a grid or even linear fashion?

My current solution is linear, top to bottom, but the images really call for a grid layout of some sort.

Thoughts?

Comment: How do you feel about an automatic collage creator program? One can set borders, specific image size frames and final size. The programs will then drop them into the final shape in a purportedly pleasing arrangement.

Comment: @fred_dot_u That might work, but I'm wondering more if there is a design pattern that this is called or some principles to follow

Comment: What is it for? web/mobile or print?

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a web page, you could have clickable thumbnails all at 1:1 aspect ratios, and clicking on them would reveal the image at full size/proper aspect ratio.

For a fixed page layout obviously a different approach would be necessary.

One option is to create a regular grid of 1:1 squares, and to fit and centre the content within these squares. So all the images would need to be resized so that the width or height would not exceed the size of the squares. You could remove the grid/guides afterwards.

[image]